# Display images stored on Firebase Storage from Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, cors, firebase-storage, flutter-web, google-cloud-sdk

I am unable to retrieve images stored on Firebase storage on Flutter Web.

***Accompanied by:***

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at <firebase-storage-photo-url> has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [Google Cloud Docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors)

> Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) allows interactions between resources from different origins, something that is normally prohibited in order to prevent malicious behavior.

Following the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files), here is how to solve this:

1. Download `gsutil`, a Google Cloud CLI, [instructions on how to install can be found here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install).
2. Create `cors.json` file with the following content:

```
    [
      {
        "origin": ["*"],
        "method": ["GET"],
        "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
      }
    ]
```

3. Now use the CLI to deploy `cors.json` rules using this command:

```
    gsutil cors set cors.json gs://<your-cloud-storage-bucket>
```

You can find the path for your Firebase storage bucket in Firebase console under Storage feature.